# Size of a "Gallons" in recipes

Tags: measurements

I'm from the UK and only really work in metric. Im having a bit of trouble converting [this](http://www.britishbrewer.com/2009/12/recipe-chiswick-esb-version-1-0/) recipe into metric. In brewing does a "gallon" mean the imperial or american gallon? (23L or 18L)

Comment: Just to be clear, I think the linked to recipe was made for a 2.5 gallon batch.  I haven't worked off of recipes from hopville, but it says 2.5 gallon batch size under the extract/grist section.

Comment: HopVille will automatically convert recipes between US and metric units. Check the two tabs at the bottom of the recipe page, in the center.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It refers to American gallons.  5 gal.=18.92L